# Image upload multiple maximum of four images only [php]

Tags: php, upload, image-uploading

This is my code in uploading an image. It is working but only one image. I wanted to change it so that it will enable my users to upload maximum of 4 images. Could anyone guide me on this?

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));


    $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif","");        
    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions) === false){
        $msg = '<div class="error">Extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.</div>'; 
    }
    if($file_size > 10000000){
        $msg = '<div class="error">File size must not be larger than 10MB</div>';
    }

    if(empty($msg)==true){
        $newname= (rand(1, 99999999999).".".$file_ext);     
        $dir_separator = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $folder = "uploads";

        $uploaddate = date("M-d-Y");

        $destination_path = dirname(__FILE__).$dir_separator.$folder.$dir_separator.$uploaddate.$dir_separator;

        if(!is_dir($destination_path)) mkdir($destination_path);

        $target_path = $destination_path.$newname;
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_path);

        if(empty($file_name) == false){
        $file_location = "/".$uploaddate."/".$newname;
         }
        else
         { 
         $file_location = "";
         }

        //SQL Insert code here
        echo "Upload complete";

    }
}
```

This is my form

```
<form id="support-form" action="" name="support-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="subject-message-wrap"> <br/>
                <div class="message-text" style="text-align:center;">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" style="width:98%; max-width: 98%;" placeholder="Write your reply here..." required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!---UPLOAD FILE--->
            <div class="wrap-upload">
                <div>
                <label style="color:#009fdb;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Attach an image: </label>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" multiple/>

                </div> 
                <br/>
                <div class="submit-button-wrap">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Reply" name="submit" id="submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="cancel" id="cancel">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!---Code End UPLOAD FILE--->
            </form>
```

Edited #1:
Issue on my database table. My table looks like this.

[image: table name = support]

What i'm thinking is to add new 3 fields for the additional image location(url). Any other good idea better than mine?

Comment: Calling Masta @Fred-ii- have deep thought need to be fixed. If available.

Comment: @xkevin : You can upload as many as photos you want but you would need to have multiple input file fields for that..!

Comment: you just store the all path into another table by any user unique id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it :

**Note :** If you want to upload multiple photos you would need then to have multiple `file` inputs as :

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="image" >
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="image" >
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="image" >
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="image" >
<input type="submit" value="Send files" >
</form>
```

And then later you can get all the images as on submit button :

```
$images = $_POST['images'];
for($i=0;$i<count($images);$i++)
{
// Here you need to repeat your upload whole PHP Code for each photo 
// to upload all of them
}
```

**Reference URL :**

> http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Another Part Of Your Question :

### To Store All 4 Images In Your Database:

**Solution :** You don't need to have multiple fields to save those values in there.! Simply you can save the images names in one field like this way :

```
<?php
$images = array();
$images[0]['images'] = "image1,image2,image3,image4";
$images[1]['images'] = "image1,image2,image3,image4";
$images[2]['images'] = "image1,image2,image3,image4";
//After fetching your data from your database 
//You can simply explode the image column data in order to separate each image value
for($i=0;$i<count($images);$i++) {
$image = explode(",",$images[$i]['images']);
echo "Image 1 :".$image[0]."</br>";
echo "Image 2 :".$image[1]."</br>";
echo "Image 3 :".$image[2]."</br>";
echo "Image 4 :".$image[3]."</br></br></br></br></br>";
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT OF CODE :**

```
Image 1 :image1
Image 2 :image2
Image 3 :image3
Image 4 :image4




Image 1 :image1
Image 2 :image2
Image 3 :image3
Image 4 :image4




Image 1 :image1
Image 2 :image2
Image 3 :image3
Image 4 :image4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have another issue on my database table. Guide me please..

Comment: Besides let me know what is your issue I will try to help you fix it..!

Comment: Answer updated take a look at it and if solves your problem so I am sure you will accept it..!

Comment: Nice! Thank you @Umair Shah Yousafzai. I will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Change input name:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" multiple />
```

Change the PHP code to handle multiple files upload. Great example here:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Limit images count on client side (JavaScript) and server (PHP).

Comment: Thank you! I will check them.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){


$num_files = count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);  // file count


for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
{

    if($i<4)
    {
      //here checking only four file



$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
$file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
$file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
$file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'][$i];   
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'][$i])));


$extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif","");        
if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions) === false){
    $msg = '<div class="error">Extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.</div>'; 
}
if($file_size > 10000000){
    $msg = '<div class="error">File size must not be larger than 10MB</div>';
}

if(empty($msg)==true){
    $newname= (rand(1, 99999999999).".".$file_ext);     
    $dir_separator = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $folder = "uploads";

    $uploaddate = date("M-d-Y");

    $destination_path = dirname(__FILE__).$dir_separator.$folder.$dir_separator.$uploaddate.$dir_separator;

    if(!is_dir($destination_path)) mkdir($destination_path);

    $target_path = $destination_path.$newname;
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_path);

    if(empty($file_name) == false){
    $file_location = "/".$uploaddate."/".$newname;
     }
    else
     { 
     $file_location = "";
     }

    //SQL Insert code here
    echo "Upload complete";


    }

}
 }

 }
```

Comment: you just store the all path into another table by any user unique id

Comment: I would like to do that, but since my website is currently live, I just want to add another field to the table so that all old image uploads will be in the same place, not get  affected.

Comment: if u want statically 4 file only upload means add 3 extra field is enough otherwise you want new table for more no of file @xkevin